# How do I make crontab generate a unique log each time it runs a job?

Tags: linux, crontab

Here is the crontab job

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 /home/scripts/script.py >> /home/scripts/logs/log.log 2>&1
```

How do I generate a new log every time the job is run?

I am cool with adding an increasing counter to the log file each time it is generated.
Do not know how to do this.

Do I really have to run another cron job to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `date` command to generate a unique(ish) filename:

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 /home/scripts/script.py > /home/scripts/logs/"`date +\%d\%m\%y_\%H\%M\%S`".log 2>&1
```

EDIT: **Make sure to escape the percentage signs** (`\%`). They have a [special meaning](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/) in cron and the crontab will return an error.

That way, a new log file (called `<date_time>.log`) will be created every time your job runs.

```
$ date; touch "`date +%d%m%y_%H%M%S`.log"
  Tue Sep 25 04:39:25 CEST 2012
$ ls *log
  250912_043925.log
```

Assuming your script does not run more often than once a second (which it can't if you are running a simple crontab), you should be fine.

If, as suggested in the comments, your script is run by different users, you can add the user name to the log file's name:

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 /home/scripts/script.py > /home/scripts/logs/$(echo -n `whoami`_`date +\%d\%m\%y_\%H\%M\%S`).log 2>&1
```

Comment: .. assuming the job only runs as one user. Otherwise, this is a good solution.

Comment: @seaworthy There was a mistake in my orignial answer, please see my edit.

Comment: @terdon, the original did not work, trying the fixed version now.